# Was Drishtadyumna invincible and not slayable until he had killed Drona?

Tags: mahabharata, dronacharya, boon

Since he had the boon that he was going to kill Drona - he was basically invincible until he had accomplished that.  Does the Mahabharata talk about this?

Comment: Are you asking about the boon or invincibility due to boon? @S K

Comment: Yes both he and shikhandi had to be unslayable/invincible until they had defeated their respective targets to fulfull their boons.  Ashwatthama kills them only after everything was over @hanugm